# Get users with different roles and call function on each of them (user_meta)

Tags: functions, users, user-roles, user-meta

First of all, I have a custom function in `functions.php` that gets some author information. This works on great on single posts with a single author.

```
<?php function the_author_box() { ?>
<div class="widget about-the-author-widget">        
    <h3 class="widget-title">Over de auteur</h3>
    <div class="author-header clear">
        <div class="author-avatar-wrap"><?php echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?></div>
        <h4 class="author-name"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="author-description"><p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p></div>
    <ul class="author-meta">
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'url' ) ) { ?>
            <li class="url">
                <a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'url' ); ?>" title="De website van <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?>">Website</a>
            </li>
            <?php // a lot more metas ?>
    </ul>
</div>
    <?php
} ?>
```

But now I'm designing a custom page template to display the 'the_author_box' for every user who is either a contributor or an administrator. All on the same page.

I figured I could get the users by doing so (borrowed from stackexchange). Build a new function:

```
function get_clients() { 

    $users = array();
    $roles = array('author', 'contributor', 'administrator');

    foreach ($roles as $role) :
        $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
            'fields' => 'all_with_meta', 
            'role' => $role, 
            'orderby' => 'display_name'
            ) );
        $results = $users_query->get_results();
        if ($results) $users = array_merge($users, $results);
    endforeach;

    return $users;
}
```

Call the users, and execute the function for every user:

```
<?php
$users_array = get_clients();
foreach ($users_array as $user) {
$user->the_author_box();
?>
```

But that doesn't work. I am guessing because it's still 'the author meta' that's called, and not the user's meta.

How can I call a function for `$user->function()`. In other words, how can I get meta information from that user?

Answer (score 1):

First, always `var_dump()` something if you aren't sure what exactly you got. If you ain't got XDebug installed and configured, just use

```
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', htmlspecialchars( var_export( $dumpMe, true ) ) );
```

which will bring up an equally informative response.

About the `WP_User_Query`) IIRC it returns objects which are instances of `WP_User`. You can test that with

```
$user instanceof WP_User AND print 'Yes, I am a WP_User object';
```

If that is the case, simply use

```
var_dump( get_user_meta( $user->user_id ) );
```

and you should be fine. Btw, there's no real Author Meta.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what this var_dump does? And how would I implement this?

Comment: Search Google for `XDebug` and `var_dump`, as well as `print_r` and `var_export`.

Comment: Well that's a disappointing answer.

Comment: @BramVanroy How would one comment explain such broad (and basic PHP) topics better than extensive search results from Google? Answers here serve a purpose of helping you _further_, not answering each and every question you got in mind. Especially if it barely touches the WordPress-topic.

Comment: True, and I definitely *will* Google all those terms, but it doesn't answer my original question. "I have tried this, but it doesn't work. Maybe this is the problem. How do I make this work?" So, an answer would also cover how I should implement this. I don't need the explanation of everyting (it's useful though, but I can google one thing and another) but I need to know how to implement it.

Comment: @BramVanroy I gave you all the tools. You just need to inspect the results, then proceed from there or comment what doesn't work and _in which way_ it doesn't work. The debug statements are there to show you where dumping results would make sense.